# newtheorem definition and numbering

Tags: environments, amsthm, newtheorem

I want to create two environments, `problem` and `subproblem`. I will use the `problem` environment to define main problems, and `subproblem` to define variations to the main problem. I'd like to have the `subproblem` numbering as children of the `problem` numbering. I mean that I like to have something as

```
Problem 1: Definition of Problem 1
Problem 2: Definition of Problem 2

Problem 1.1: Definition of the first variation of Problem 1
Problem 1.2: Definition of the second variation of Problem 1
Problem 2.1: Definition of the first variation of Problem 2
```

and so on.

I created the environment `problem` by means of the `\newtheorem` command and the first `problem` as

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{problem}
    \label{prob1}
    Definition...
\end{problem}
```

Now I'd like to create similarly the `subproblem` environment. How can I do, so that the `subproblem` will reference to the numbering of the associated `problem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember the last “subproblem” number. For this it is mandatory that each `problem` environment you plan to define variations of has a `\label`.

When `problem*` is processed, it looks at the last number referring to the same label and steps it.

You can also label the problem variations, as shown in the example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{refcount}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{subproblem}{Problem}

\newenvironment{problem*}[1]
 {%
  \ifcsname problem@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\xdef\csname problem@#1\endcsname{%
      \the\numexpr\csname problem@#1\endcsname+1\relax
    }%
  \else
    \expandafter\xdef\csname problem@#1\endcsname{1}%
  \fi
  \edef\thesubproblem{%
    \getrefnumber{#1}.\csname problem@#1\endcsname
  }%
  \subproblem
 }
 {\endsubproblem}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}\label{first}
Definition of Problem 1
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}\label{second}
Definition of Problem 2
\end{problem}

\begin{problem*}{first}
Definition of the first variation of Problem 1
\end{problem*}

\begin{problem*}{first}\label{secondoffirst}
Definition of the second variation of Problem 1
\end{problem*}

\begin{problem*}{second}
Definition of the first variation of Problem 2
\end{problem*}

As we saw in problem~\ref{secondoffirst}

\end{document}
```

Note that this requires two or three LaTeX runs when a `problem` is added, but you'll get the message

```latex
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

in case a new run is needed.

[image]

Comment: Great! It works. Just what I was searching for. :)

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\newtheorem` has an option with which you can refer to its parent. So you can use `\newtheorem{subproblem}{Subproblem}[problem]` to achieve what you want (at least, if I understand you correctly).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{subproblem}{Subproblem}[problem]

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \label{prob1}
    Definition ...
\end{problem}

\begin{subproblem}
    \label{subprob1}
    Definition ...
\end{subproblem}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

---

If you need the problems and subproblems in a random order, you can set the problem counter manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{subproblem}{Subproblem}[problem]

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \label{prob1}
    Definition ...
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    \label{prob2}
    Definition ...
\end{problem}

\setcounter{problem}{1}
\begin{subproblem}
    \label{subprob11}
    Definition ...
\end{subproblem}

\begin{subproblem}
    \label{subprob12}
    Definition ...
\end{subproblem}

\stepcounter{problem}
\begin{subproblem}
    \label{subprob21}
    Definition ...
\end{subproblem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, I should define the subproblems just after the associated main problem. If I have a situation like the example I provided above (where first the problems are defined and then the subproblems in a random order), this solution does not give what I want.

Comment: You can use `\setcounter{problem}{1}` to manually set the problem counter. See my edit.